# function to average in an array

Tags: c++, average

So I have to create a function that will average the numbers inputted by the user in an array which can go up to 10 numbers, but could be stopped anywhere between the first input and the tenth by the user inputting -1

i'm unsure whether its similar to finding the highest number which i've done

What I have going right now is but I have no clue on how to get it to average the numbers since its not going to be divided by a set number

```
cout << "The average of the results = " << calc_average(score) << "\n";
cout << "The lowest of the results = " << find_lowest(score) << "\n";
system("Pause");


}

double calc_average(double a[])
{




}

double find_highest(double a[])
{
double temp = 0;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(a[i]>temp)
        temp=a[i];
}
return temp;
 }
```

EDIT: To clarify, the max number is results a user can enter is 10 thats why it goes up to 10.

Comment: Then divide it by... *a variable?*

Comment: Well your `find_highest` isn't right because of *'could be stopped anywhere'*. Your loop shouldn't go to 10, it should go to how ever many numbers the user entered. Again it's not a set number, it's a variable.

Answer (score 0):

> What I have going right now is but I have no clue on how to get it to
>   average the numbers since its not going to be divided by a set number

You should keep track of how many numbers the user has input by just keeping a counter.

Then you can use that as your divisor, and get the average.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
double calc_average(double a[])
{
    double fAverage = 0.0f;

    double fCount = 0.0f;
    double fTotal = 0.0f;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] < 0)
            break;

        fTotal += a[i];
        fCount += 1.0f;
    }

    if( fCount > 0.0f )
        fAverage = fTotal / fCount;

    return fAverage;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the iterator as a counter and a variable named `avg` here to store the average. And finally just return the value of `avg`.

```
double find_highest(double a[])
{
    double avg, temp = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>temp)
            temp += a[i];
    }
    avg = temp/i;
    return avg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you (though I might have an off by one error in there somewhere). The secret is the extra condition in the for loop.

```
double calc_average(double a[])
{
    int i;
    float sum = 0.0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10 && a[i] > -1; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    if(i > 0)
    {
        return sum / i;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0.0;  /* Technically there is no average in this case. */
    }
}
```